# How to get the id of each first element of a nexted div in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

here is my HTML code

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="computer">
        <div id="items">
            <div id="1">hp</div>
            <div id="2">compaq</div>
            <div id="3">toshiba</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="laptop">
        <div id="1">i5</div>
        <div id="2">dual core</div>
        <div id="3">i3</div>
    </div>
    <div id="printer">
        <div id="laser">hp laser</div>
    </div>
    <div id="cpu">
        <div id="item">
            <div id="1">pintuim</div>
            <div id="2">celeron</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="scanner">
    <div id="canon">
            <div>canon</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>`
```

I am trying to get the id of each first element of the parent div
that is to get an 
`array=[computer, laptop, printer, cpu, scanner]`

here is my jquery code but it's taking everything.

`var a = $("div.content :nth-child(1)")find("*").toArray();`

please I need some help thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a selector in jQuery which will return the first level of children: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/z81d8a0s/)**

```
var a=[];
$("#parent > div").each(function(){ // using > will return the first level of children
    a.push($(this).attr('id'));
});
alert(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

Those are children of the `#parent` element so you can iterate over that and create an array out of it using [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map)

```js
var array = $('#parent').children().map(function() {
  return this.id;
}).get();

snippet.log(array)
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
  <div id="computer">
    <div id="items">
      <div id="1">hp</div>
      <div id="2">compaq</div>
      <div id="3">toshiba</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="laptop">
    <div id="1">i5</div>
    <div id="2">dual core</div>
    <div id="3">i3</div>
  </div>
  <div id="printer">
    <div id="laser">hp laser</div>
  </div>
  <div id="cpu">
    <div id="item">
      <div id="1">pintuim</div>
      <div id="2">celeron</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="scanner">
    <div id="canon">
      <div>canon</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quit anwser but i still have a small problem I need to retrieved only this: `computer,laptop,printer,cpu,scanner`. not all the sub childreen of the parent thanks

Comment: @tonypro if you see tbe above code the retrieved value is only `computer,laptop,printer,cpu,scanner`

Comment: yeah, escuse me i was making a misteake